# How to run java program from different directory in Linux

Tags: java, compiling, directory

How to run a Java program from different directory in Ubuntu?

Comment: Like a jar file? Does `java -jar dir/myfile.jar` not work?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run java programs after installing java(open JDK or Oracle Java), you need to set java environment-variable.

> An environment variable is a dynamic-named value that can affect the way running processes will behave on a computer.

At first run:

```
>>> sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

"to find out where your java installation is."

Next you need to add the path in above command to the java environment-variable. For that you need to edit your profile file.

```
>>> sudo /etc/profile
```

You need to add this line to the end of your profile file.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17
```

(after equal sign add your path copied from above instead of /usr.../till the version specification)

Save the file and in order to save the path run:

```
>>> source /etc/profile
```

After these steps you can run Java programs by `cd` to where your file is and then run and execute whatever you want.

Example: you have a file test.java

Compile your file:

```
>>> javac test.java
```

Run your file:

```
>>> java test
```